# source code string cannot contain null bytes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, cx-freeze

Whenever i run code using `python demo_2.py py2exe` it gives me this error.

```
C:\CarlomanSystems>python setup.py py2exe
    running py2exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        setup(console=['filw-1.py'])
      File "C:\Python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
        self._run()
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
        builder.analyze()
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 158, in analyze
        self.mf.import_package(modname[:-2])
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 98, in import_package
        self.safe_import_hook("%s.%s" % (name, modname))
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 401, in _scan_code
        self._scan_code(c, mod)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 401, in _scan_code
        self._scan_code(c, mod)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 401, in _scan_code
        self._scan_code(c, mod)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 401, in _scan_code
        self._scan_code(c, mod)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 288, in _find_and_load
        self._gcd_import(parent)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 356, in _find_and_load
        if module.__code__:
      File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 622, in __code__
        self.__code_object__ = self.__loader__.get_code(self.__name__)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I tried out cx_freeze also but it give me the same error.

my source code has only one line, and that is:

```
print('hello world!')
```

I have opened it with notepad++ but it isn't shows any null characters.
i have uninstall and reinstall both the library py2exe and cx_freeze, but it isn't solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

November 2016 there is still no Python 3.5 and newest no support in sight for py2exe.
Try this
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html